# Assigned to field in Case Table- Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

In Case Form,Based on the group selected in **Assignment group** field ,the **assigned to** field is listing some users which belongs to it in CRM UI.

Now I want to retrieve the same users using normal REST API. Please suggest REST API to list the users based on a group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users linked to groups is stored in table sys_user_grmember. In the example I search for all Users in Group named "Application Development".

GET https://YOURINSTANCE.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_grmember?sysparm_query=%22groupSTARTSWITHApplication%20Development%22&sysparm_limit=10

You can easily test the REST Api with the rest api explorer from SNOW: https://YOURINSTANCE.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2F$restapi.do

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more info on the exact requirement, so i can be more precise?

As far as I know, you can create a rest message to get the users inside a group and show the list wherever you want. 
This would require three things from your side.
a) Creating a rest message in Snow.
b) Creating a script includes calling the rest message.
c) A client script or trigger which initiates the rest call using client script.

Hope this helps.

Regards.